# support new facebook API instead of $facebook->api_client->profile_setFBML($profileContent);

Tags: php, api, facebook

I looked at Facebook page, and they not supported with the PHP Api:
$facebook->api_client->profile_setFBML($profileContent);

can anyone help me with another possible API to use.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [profile.setFBML](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Profile.setFBML) method is deprecated, and about to be phased out entirely.  You won't be able to use it anymore, and indeed, there is no point, since the profile boxes are going to cease to exist as well.

You are going to have to migrate whatever it is you're doing to [Application Tabs](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Tabbed_Profile) instead.  It will be the only way to put application content into a user's profile very shortly (timeline is "[Early 2010](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Developer_Roadmap)").